LSTM stuck on image generation
I created an LSTM for generating next image in a sequence (I know CNN is for image generation but I need the entire image not just the filters to give to the next iteration of the sequence). So I have a dataset it contains images (frames from a movie) and I created sequences of it like if 1 scene contains eg. n images and I have s sequence length then the input would be image_1 through image_s and output is image_s+1, the next input is image_2 through image_s+1 and the output is image_s+2 and so on.
The model is the next:
class LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_len, hidden_size, num_layers):
        super(LSTM, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_len, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(hidden_size, input_len)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(.2)


    def forward(self, X):
        hidden_states = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, X.size(0), self.hidden_size, device=device)
        cell_states = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, X.size(0), self.hidden_size, device=device)
        out, _ = self.lstm(X, (hidden_states, cell_states))
        out = self.dropout(out)
        out = self.output_layer(out[:, -1, :])
        return out

training is:
def train(num_epochs, model, loss_func, optimizer):
    total_steps = loader.getSizeWithBatch()

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        loader.reset()
        for item in range(total_steps-1):
            element = loader.next()[0]
            x_images,y_image = element
            x_images = x_images.reshape(-1, sequence_len, input_len)
            output = model(x_images)
            y_image = y_image.reshape(-1,input_len)
            loss = loss_func(output, y_image)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            if (item + 1) % 1 == 0:
                print(f'Epoch: {epoch + 1}; Batch: {item + 1} / {total_steps};Loss: {loss.item():>4f}')

        if (epoch + 1) % int(config['SAVE']['model_save_interval']) == 0:
            if (epoch + 1) % int(config['SAVE']['clean_save_interval']) == 0:
                torch.save(model.state_dict(), os.path.join(config['PATH']['model_path'], config['PATH']['model_name'] + str(epoch+1)))
            else:
                torch.save(model.state_dict(), os.path.join(config['PATH']['model_path'], config['PATH']['model_name']))

The Loader leads images in the form of tensors presequenciated from files because of memory usage.
I use MSE loss and Adam as optimizer.
The problem is when I train it the error reaches the 0.003 which is the goal since I normalize the values by dividing them with 255, but when I predict it creates a little blurry sort of meshing the scene together images and the predicted image is always the same regardless of the input even if the input is from an other scene it will creates the same image, when I subtract the color value of the different output images the value is 0 so every single output image is completely the same.
The end result looks like if I put every single image from the dataset under each other as layers
I have tried to add Droput, increase the neurons of the hidden size which is 128 now, tried to increase the number of layers, different epochs creates the same image just a little less blurry but its the same, I decreased the learning rate from .001 to .0001 and its all the same

MSE is a bad loss function for image generation for this exact reason. Two images that have low MSE difference can look very different visually. Look into the losses used for image generation
